# Report transaction exits silently after selection screen

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I wrote a basic report with a selection screen. When I run the transaction I created for it the selection screen displays and is functional. However when I continue past the selection screen the program just silently exits without any warning or error message.

In debugger the program will end silently when it reaches the START-OF-SELECTION program event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when you create a transaction for a report with a selection screen but defined it with the incorrect type as a dialog transaction instead of a report transaction.

Recreate the transaction, selecting the second option in the "Start object" block: "Program and selection screen (report transaction)".

*Caveat: on some systems a dialog transaction calling a report will still work even though the type is strictly speaking incorrect.*